# JQuery won't load clear url?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to load simple codeignitier controller, but no success i get **404** error.

It looks like jquery load does not support pretty/clear urls? Is it possible and how?

When i try to load some file using this same code it works perfectly, but when i try to load codeignitier controller function nope, i get 404 in Console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#season").load('https://www.example.co/index.php/system/example');
       //i already tried without 'index.php'
    });
</script>
```

when i check does load function works using some simple file, it works perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#season").load('https://www.example.co/test.php');
    });
</script>
```

and controller:

```
public function example(){
    echo "EXAMPLE";
}
```

This link exists and is not 404 (of course without example):

> https://www.example.co/index.php/system/example

[image]

Comment: have you checked your route

Comment: @Snm route is correct. I tried also using base_url function, result is same. 
Is possible to load pretty links by load function? I know that "ugly" urls works, but how to use pretty links?

Comment: can you just tell me how you are using the htaccess and the route

Comment: @Snm I rewrite index.php in .htaccess.  
/ => public_html => application => index.php /controllers => System.php
/ => public_html => application => index.php /views => test.php
From test.php i call System.php function example().

Answer (score 0):

Try by pass it as

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url('controller/method'); ?>'
```

Comment: Can you give me complete example, how i can call this?

When i try it, it redirects me to /system/example

Comment: is system is your controller and example is method ?

Comment: `window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url('system/example'); ?>';`

Comment: I already try this, it redirects me to system/example. I want to load system/example inside system/test, not to redirect.

Comment: I think this done like you can use ajax and its result set into div's html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94333/discussion-between-bhavin-shah-and-docnet).

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding '?' before index.php. 
So this is result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PI = {

    onReady: function() {
        $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '/index.php?/system/getseasons/SC0', 
        success: function (response) { 
            alert('success');
            $("#season").html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
              console.log(xhr.statusText);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log(error);
        }


        })
    },

    };

    $( document ).ready( PI.onReady );

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like your rewrite rule is incorrect and doesn't remove the `?`. Have a look at [the suggested format](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) and compare it to your won `.htaccess`. But before, try wether you need the same url when directly entering into the browser.